# Upgrade Django installation on AWS elasticbeanstalk

Tags: django, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Django 1.9.12 project running on EBS. I'd like to upgrade to Django 1.11 which I've done in the dev environment. How can I force EBS to update to 1.11? I hoped it might be a simple case of updating the requirements.txt but that hasn't worked with `eb deploy`

Would it be easier just to create a new EBS project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should be able to do this no problem by updating the requirements.txt file.

Please post the error details you are getting and you requirements.txt file.

Comment: Okay... found it. Problem with req.txt. BOM. And additionally the static location wasn't set up properly... learning curve right?